# Add footer menu to theme support only one header menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i Download and activate theme but i find that there is no way with setting to add links to footer menu because its support only one header menu

i download the Genesis Simple Menus from here https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-simple-menus/ and add this code in the functions.php file :-

```
// display the Footer Navigation
add_action('genesis_before_footer', 'wdm_add_footer_menu');
function wdm_add_footer_menu()
{
    wp_nav_menu(array(
     'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
     'container_id' => 'footer' ,
     'menu_class' => 'menu-tertiary',
     'theme_location' => 'footer',
     'depth' => 1,
     'items_wrap'  => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
      ) );
}
```

but nothing happened is that anyway to make this theme have footer location menu???

Answer (score 0):

Add `register_nav_menu('footer', 'Footer Menu');` in your functions.php
See this for details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu

Comment: i do and once i put the code it create primary location but not footer

Comment: i change code to this add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'footer', __( 'footer Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
} but still not work

Comment: its create footer location and i create menu and add links to it but still not work nothing show in the footer

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link,hope it helps your cause,

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/

Comment: this is in the footer file i think it must changed too      <div class="span4 footer_credits right_aligned">
     <?php echo get_theme_mod('credits', ''); ?>
    </div>